What is the password for ubuntu user?


I am using Oracle Virtual Box v7.1.4 r165100.
I downloaded "ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64" image.
I created a username and password as part of the image setup.
There was an error towards the end of the image deployement, but Ubuntu still managed to start.
When I start terminal I can only see Ubuntu users (please see screenshot). i cannot see the username I created.
That's fine. I can still create my own user, but I am worrieed if I logout then I won't be able to login: what is the password for user "ubuntu" please?

Please note: I tried blank, "reverse", "ubuntu", "admin". None worked.

It seems to be the live session(similar to the one you installed). It is not the installed system. Try removing the ISO from virtualbox, and then booting. If it does not work, please try to install again, and if there is an error message during installation, please post it

It looks like you are running a live Ubuntu system (booted from the iso file). That is not the installed Ubuntu system where you created your custom user ID and password. You can confirm that it is a live system by running df -h | grep '/$'. The output line starts with /cow in a live system and typically with /dev/'something' in an installed system. -- If live, please boot the virtual system without pointing to the iso file, and your system should boot into the installed system.
